# Return a value from inside a Fiber

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, fibers, node-fibers

I'm trying to provide a collection having its methods wrapped in fibers for synchronous looking calls.

```
const Fiber = require('fibers');
const wrapInFiber = require('./wrapInFiber');

let db;
Fiber(function () {
  db = wrapInFiber({
    url: global.__MONGO_URI__,
    config: { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    databaseName: global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__,
    collections: ['users'],
  });
  console.log('DB', db.users);
}).run();

module.exports.Users = db.users; <-- undefined
```

Console log outputs the value but `db.users` passed to the `module.exports` is undefined because either it runs before the fiber is done or rather outside the fiber, I presume? So, how can I pass the value to the `module.exports` correctly?

The only remotely close answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708961/returning-a-value-from-inside-fibersnodejs) which I tried to mimic but failed, maybe because his wrapped function involved no fibers related code unlike mine.

`WrapInFiber` just in case. It's adapted from this [library](https://github.com/pabloLagioia/fiber-mongo).

```
const Fiber = require('fibers');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

module.exports = function ({ url, config, databaseName, collections }) {
  const Collection = function (db, name) {
    this.collection = db.collection(name);
  };

  Collection.prototype.count = function (query, options) {
    query = query || {};
    options = options || {};
    const fiber = Fiber.current;
    this.collection.count(query, options, function (err, records) {
      fiber.run(records);
    });
    return Fiber.yield();
  };

  Collection.prototype.find = function (query, options) {
    query = query || {};
    options = options || {};
    const fiber = Fiber.current;
    this.collection.find(query, options).toArray(function (err, records) {
      fiber.run(records);
    });
    return Fiber.yield();
  };

  Collection.prototype.findOne = function (query, options) {
    return this.find(query, options)[0];
  };

  Collection.prototype.update = function (query, options) {
    const fiber = Fiber.current;
    this.collection.update(query, options, function (err, records) {
      fiber.run(records);
    });
    return Fiber.yield();
  };

  Collection.prototype.insert = function (document) {
    const fiber = Fiber.current;
    this.collection.insert(document, function (err, records) {
      fiber.run(records);
    });
    return Fiber.yield();
  };

  Collection.prototype.remove = function (document) {
    const fiber = Fiber.current;
    this.collection.remove(document, function (err, records) {
      fiber.run(records);
    });
    return Fiber.yield();
  };

  const fiber = Fiber.current;

  MongoClient.connect(url, config, function (err, connection) {
    const obj = {
      close() {
        connection.close();
      },
    };
    const db = connection.db(databaseName);
    collections.forEach(function (collectionName) {
      obj[collectionName] = new Collection(db, collectionName);
    });
    fiber.run(obj);
  });

  return Fiber.yield();
};
```

Comment: wow, this looks really complicated. Why do you need this? DB collection methods in meteor already run in a fiber and are synchronous. So why can't you just use `Meteor.users.find()` directly? Why do you need your own version of fiber-wrapped DB queries?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to write tests for some Meteor package but the tests are being run without invoking the package rather importing the file because we're trying to migrate out of Meteor and I don't want to add any Meteor related code, so I need to stub out the collection in order to be able to invoke its methods like find, update, etc.
For context: 
https://github.com/unchainedshop/unchained/pull/253/files#diff-6df3da198f1cf979745620d92e4c6427b2be079099b2fb03b1ac20ec4f3711cb

Comment: I need to stub the Users collection to be able to test Roles.getUserRoles for instance

https://github.com/unchainedshop/unchained/pull/253/files#diff-c21f2fc02211ac71c1abfa4bd9c7d9096284110f1e67d22361ac34578f21255bR159

Comment: @HarryAdel is there a reason, why you are not using the `Future` class as [proposed  in the fibers documentation](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers#futures)?

Comment: How do you propose I use it? I tried something like this but it's not working.
```
const Fiber = require('fibers');
const Future = require('fibers/future');
const wrapInFiber = require('./wrapInFiber');

const fn = Future.wrap(wrapInFiber);
const future = new Future();
Fiber(function () {
  const db = fn({
    url: global.__MONGO_URI__,
    config: { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    databaseName: global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__,
    collections: ['users'],
  }).wait();
  return future.return(db.users);
}).run();

module.exports.Users = future;
```

Comment: I pushed my local changes. So now to test things out for yourselves all you have to do is clone the branch
https://github.com/unchainedshop/unchained/pull/253
and run
npx jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit tests/roles.test.js

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't solve the issues of fibers I managed to solve the initial problem which led to this path of stubbing Meteor collections. All it took was a simple [Sinon stub](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/).

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
require('sinon-mongo');

const Users = sinon.mongo.collection({
  findOne: sinon
    .stub()
    .withArgs({ _id: 'user' }, { fields: { roles: 1 } })
    .returns({ _id: 'user', roles: [] }),
});

module.exports.Users = Users;
```